# How can I convert a Series object from a string to numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem. I want to calculate the jaccard similarity of a column for some Customers (cust_id). My function for this is the following:

```
def set_sim(cust_id, data, column):
    sim_set = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        z = set(data.loc[cust_id,[column]]).intersection(set(data.loc[i,[column]]))
        sim_set.append(float(len(z))/(len(data.loc[cust_id,[column]])+len(data.loc[i,[column]])-len(z)))
    sim_set = pd.DataFrame(sim_set)
    return sim_set
```

The issue is that my column is a Series object and the values are like this ['1,3,16,17,19'] and not ['1','3','16','17','19'] so the intersection is not computed correctly.

Notice that my column contains the unique IDs of products that a customer can have so the number of elements in the column is not the same everywhere.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `series.astype(str)` would convert the series objects to string

Comment: Can you post an example of the column in question? It's not clear to me if cells contain a list with a single comma-seoarated string or just a string or something else entirely.

Comment: @ifly6 unfortunately this does not do what I want. I need to convert the output of eg. set(bank_data.loc[0,['Products']]) from this {'1,3,16,17,19'} to {'1','3','16','17','19'}

Comment: @fsimonjetz The column is an array containing the bank products (1-20) each customer has. Some examples are 1,5,6,7 and 6,7,8,9,12,13 So it is comma seperated

Comment: Then just split it at comma using `split(',')`?

Comment: It is a Series object, so I can not use split()

Comment: Apparently you can: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: yeah my bad! But still when I run the following 
```
set(bank_data.loc[0,['Products']].str.split(',')).intersection(set(bank_data.loc[1,['Products']].str.split(',')))
```
there is the error   unhashable type: 'list' 

** As i want to find the intersection I have to use the set() to convert it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to separate the data cleaning/conversion from the function that calculates the metric. So first of all, run something like this:

```py
# example data
col_raw = pd.Series([['1,3,16,17,19'],
                     ['1,2,4,7'],
                     ['20,22,3']])

def clean_field(x):
    return [int(s) for s in x[0].split(',')]

col_clean = col_raw.apply(clean_field)
col_clean
```

```
0    [1, 3, 16, 17, 19]
1          [1, 2, 4, 7]
2           [20, 22, 3]
dtype: object
```

Then you can write your Jaccard function to expect such a nice series of lists of integers as input.